# How to add Id or class to last meta in wc_display_order_meta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add id or class to only the last item meta in the array in wc_display_item_meta.

Example:

```
<ul class="wc_item_meta">'
<li> <Strong class="wc_item_meta_label">Weight</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 24kg </p></li>
<li> <Strong class="wc_item_meta_label">Height</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 6 feet </p></li>
<li> <Strong class="wc_item_meta_label">Length</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 5 Meter </p></li>
</ul>
```

Here in this example i want the last item in array ie length in this example in bigger font than the other items in array.

Please Help!!

Comment: Why don't you just change the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the last item i.e. 5 meter in the ul by using :last-child selector and increase it's font or to select the second last child i.e. Length label you can use :nth-last-child(2) selector.
Below IS the sample snippet.

```css
.wc_item_meta li:last-child {
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wc_item_meta">'
<li> <Strong class="wc_item_meta_label">Weight</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 24kg </p></li>
<li> <Strong class="wc_item_meta_label">Height</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 6 feet </p></li>
<li> <Strong class="wc_item_meta_label strong">Length</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 5 Meter </p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but with a little change ie it worked with just " li : last-child " instead of mentioning the class before li.

Comment: welcome. But without mentioning the class before  "li : last-child". it will apply to any unordered list in that page. It's okey if you want that kind of behaviour but keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add to it another class with `!important` inside to override the previous class.

Also change the location of class, `strong` tag wont allow you to use width like `li` tag.

```css
.wc_item_meta_label{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.longer{
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wc_item_meta">'
<li class="wc_item_meta_label"> <Strong>Weight</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 24kg </p></li>
<li class="wc_item_meta_label"> <Strong>Height</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 6 feet </p></li>
<li class="wc_item_meta_label longer"> <Strong>Length</strong> </li>
<li> <p> 5 Meter </p></li>
</ul>
```